# How do you query twice using two different models in laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, model

I have in my controller a function like this.

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'user_id' => 'required|numeric',
        'role' => 'required',
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'middlename' => '',
        'lastname' => 'required',
        'phone_no' => 'required|digits:11',
        'address' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
        'state' => 'required',
        'bio' => 'required',
        ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $validator->errors();
    }
```

Then I have the first update query (using model) like this:

```
    $user = User::find($request->user_id);
    $user->firstname = $request->firstname;
    $user->middlename = $request->middlename;
    $user->lastname = $request->lastname;
    $user->phone_no = $request->phone_no;
```

The second one follows like this:

```
if($request->role == 'customer' ){
        $userInfo = Customer::where('user_id', $request->user_id);
        $userInfo->address = $request->address;
        $userInfo->city = $request->city;
        $userInfo->state = $request->state;
        $userInfo->bio = $request->bio;
    }elseif($request->role == 'employer' ){
        $userInfo = Employer::where('user_id', $request->user_id);
        $userInfo->address = $request->address;
        $userInfo->city = $request->city;
        $userInfo->state = $request->state;
        $userInfo->bio = $request->bio;
    }        

    if($user->save() && $userInfo->save()){          
        return response(array("status" => "success", 'statusCode' => 200, 'message' => 'Your Profile Was Updated'))->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
```

I used AJAX to send the data to the controller. But when I click the update button it displays this error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2451:
```

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()

**I keep getting this error. How do I resolve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following. Also check if userinfo exists before saving since you have a condition where it might not.

```
$userInfo = Customer::where('user_id', $request->user_id)->first();
$userInfo = Employer::where('user_id', $request->user_id)->first();

if($user->save() && (isset($userInfo) && $userInfo->save())){}
```

Also your code can be refactored to reduce half the stuff you do. But that's out of scope for this question.

Comment: I have corrected the line of code and it is working fine. the `isset()` will be more helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()` results because you're calling the `save()` function on the builder rather than a collection. This is because you're not actually executing your query.

```
 $userInfo = Employer::where('user_id', $request->user_id);
```

Should be

```
 $userInfo = Employer::where('user_id', $request->user_id)->first();
```

Comment: I have corrected the line of code and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

save() method can save changes in one Eloquent object.
You dont have in $userInfo variable Eloquent object. Just calling where on Model does not return Eloquent object.

Change

```
$userInfo = Customer::where('user_id', $request->user_id)->first();
$userInfo = Employer::where('user_id', $request->user_id)->first();
```